# Let $f(x)$ be twice differentiable function such that $f''(x) <0$ in $[0,2]$

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f(x)$ be twice differential function such that $f''(x) <0$ in $[0,2]$  Then which of following is correct

A) $f(0)+f(2)<2f(1)$

B) $f(0)+f(2)=2f(c), c\in(0,2)$

C) $f(0)+f(2)>2f(1)$

D) $f(0)+f(2)=2f(-2)$

Comment: Using a simple sample function, like $f(x) = -x^2$ ought to let you disprove three of these. Only thing left is to prove that the remaining one is actually true.

Comment: @Arthur B) is not actually discarded by $-x^2$, we can take $c=\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @zwim That depends on whether we take it as "there exists $c$" or "for all $c$". But yes, you may need some  other simple sample function in that case. I encourage Abc Def to experiment.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

the function is strictly concave then the answer "A" is correct

[EDIT] you can also take a look here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function

to better explain, as f(x) is concave, the mean value of f(x) in the interval (that is on the segment) $$\frac {f(0)+f(2)}{2}$$ is less than the value at the mid point $$f(1)$$

[image]

Comment: the function is twice differentiable with f''(x) <0  thus f(x) is concave

Comment: as f(x) is concave, the mean value of f(x) in the interval $$\frac {f(0)+f(2)}{2}$$ is less than the value at the mid point $$f(1)$$

Comment: no because it's strictly concave, as in the above image (e.g. log function)

Comment: because f''(x) is strictly less tha $0$

Comment: it's strictly convex (that is the opposite of concave)

Comment: B can't be true, for example if you consider f(x)=-x^2+2x the equality is false

Comment: what is true is that $$f(2)-f(0)=2f'(c), c\in(0,2)$$ that's Lagrange's Theorem